# Count number of user that at least have 1 transaction each month

Tags: sql

Count number of user that at least have 1 transaction each month
(from user month(minimum(transaction_date))) until now month(getdate())

```
User_ID Transaction_date 
1       2022-07-23 
1       2022-09-23
1       2022-08-23
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @jarlh It looks to be SQL Server.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We can use aggregation as one option:

```sql
SELECT User_ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY User_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar(7), Transaction_date, 126)) =
       DATEDIFF(month, (SELECT MIN(Transaction_Date) FROM yourTable), GETDATE()) + 1;
```